# How to restore to a new database without hardcoding data path?

Tags: sql-server

I can create a copy of a database by doing a backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE olddbname TO DISK='olddbname.bak' WITH INIT;
```

And then doing a restore:

```
RESTORE DATABASE newdbname FROM DISK='olddbname.bak' WITH REPLACE;
```

Except that this will try to restore the .mdf and .ldf with the same filenames as are already being used by olddbname.

The solution is to use the MOVE option to rename the files:

```
RESTORE DATABASE newdbname FROM DISK='olddbname.bak' WITH 
    REPLACE,
    MOVE 'olddbname' TO 'X:\DATA\newdbname.mdf',
    MOVE 'olddbname_log' TO 'X:\DATA\newdbname_log.ldf'
```

And I hate that.

If I create a new database:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdbname
```

It creates .mdf and .ldf in a default location, if I don't specify something different.

How do I get the RESTORE to create the .mdf and .ldf files in that same default location?

Comment: Determine the instance default file locations using `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')` and `SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')`. Build a dynamic `RESTORE` statement using those paths in the `MOVE` clause.

Comment: This is a question that does not deserve downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [Dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) Powershell Library and use the [Restore-DbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/restore-dbadatabase/) cmdlet.

The following example pipes the output of `get-item` (pointing to my backup file created from a backup of database zzz) into `Restore-DbaDatabase`.  I use the `-useDestinationDefaultDirectories` switch to force the restored files into the target instance default directories.  I used the -DatabaseName parameter to rename the restored database to `googly`.

```
get-item "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\zzz.bak" |
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance . -useDestinationDefaultDirectories -DatabaseName googly
```

Comment: You rock!!!!!!!

Comment: I was looking for a simple way to restore db without installing SSMS and this is the best way.